# how to use docker-compose in jenkins pipeline in docker?

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline

I'm running Jenkins in Docker.

Recent, I'm studying CI/CD so coding with Jenkins pipeline.

I want to use docker and docker coomand in Jenkins pipeline, so I connect volume docker.sock etc.

It works fine, but docker compose and it's command is not.

↓↓↓ Below is Jenkinsfile code ↓↓↓

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage ("********\n docker-compose \n********") {
            steps {
                dir("FE"){
                     sh "docker-compose version"    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

↓↓↓ Below is docker-compose error ↓↓↓

```
+ docker-compose version
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/test_deploy_front/FE@tmp/durable-4da14a9d/script.sh: 1: docker-compose: not found
```

↓↓↓ Below is docker compose(v2) error ↓↓↓

```
+ docker compose version
docker: 'compose' is not a docker command.
See 'docker --help'
```

Jenkins does not recognize not only docker compose(v2) but also docker-compose(v1) command.

Of course, I installed docker-compose-plugin(v2) and docker compose(v1) in Host server.

My current system like this ↓
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QjCV.png)
※direct image needs 10 reputations so this is link.

What should I do?

My opinion #1
Install docker-compose(v1) only in Jenkins in Docker. (Is it OK? I saw docker in docker is not good answer. Or should I think that Docker Compose is not Docker??)

Comment: Add code ans error messages as text not as image

Comment: *docker-compose: not found*  looks like docker compose is not installed

Comment: Right. 
So, like volume connect to use docker in jenkins, I want to know that other method to use outside docker-compose in Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Docker compose is now a plugin from the main binary.

You will have to map the plugins directory across.

The plugins directory will be in the following locations:

```
/usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins
/usr/local/libexec/docker/cli-plugins
/usr/lib/docker/cli-plugins
/usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins
```

I recommend confirming which directory has the plugins using ls. Once you've located the plugins directory for your system then map it across as a volume.

Ubuntu 22.04 uses /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins.

Here is my docker compose for Jenkins:

```
jenkins:
  image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
  restart: always
  privileged: true
  user: root
  ports:
    - 8080:8080
    - 50000:50000
  container_name: jenkins
  volumes:
    - /data/jenkins/:/var/jenkins_home
    - /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    - /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins:/usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins
```